# Is there an idiomatic way to find matching key and value in map in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I'm trying to find matching key and value pairs from a map. I'm using the following code:

```
(defn matches? [m k v]
  (let [val (k m)]
    (= val v)))

my-demo.core=> (matches? {:a 1 :b 2} :b 2)
true
my-demo.core=> (matches? {:a 1 :b 2} :b 3)
false
```

Another approach using `superset?`:

```
my-demo.core=> (superset? #{:a 1 :b 3} #{:a 1})
true
my-demo.core=> (superset? #{:a 1 :b 3} #{:a 2})
false
```

I have a feeling there is a better way to do this.

My question is: **Is there an idiomatic way to find matching key and value in map in Clojure?**

Comment: Your `matches?` function looks good to me, though I'd probably remove the let in this case: `(defn matches? [m k v] (= (k m) v))`.

Comment: Please expand that into an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably a small enough problem that you could just use this instead of defining a function:

```
(= ({:a 1 :b 2} :a)
   1)

=> true
```

I would say this is an idiomatic way, which will work fine for most use cases.

---

However, it depends on the behaviour you require when testing for a `nil` value. because the above method would return `true` for `:c nil`:

```
(= ({:a 1 :b 2} :c)
   nil)

=> true
```

And your function behaves the same way:

```
(matches? {:a 1 :b 2} :c nil)

=> true
```

To get around this you could use `get` with a "not found" value:

```
(= (get {:a 1 :b 2} :c ::not-found)
   nil)

=> false
```

This works fine but it's perhaps not as neat. You'd just have to make sure that your "not found" value was never the same as your test value.

---

If you wanted to really know that a map contains a key with a possibly `nil` value you would instead have to check both things. Here's a function that would do this while only doing the hash-map lookup once. It uses `(find map key)` which returns the map entry (the key-value pair) for key, or nil if the key is not present.

```
(defn contains-kv? [m k v]
  (if-let [kv (find m k)]
    (= (val kv) v)
    false))

(contains-kv? {:a 1 :b nil} :a 1)
=> true

(contains-kv? {:a 1 :b nil} :b nil)
=> true

(contains-kv? {:a 1 :b nil} :c nil)
=> false
```

---

Note: I don't think `superset?` is doing what you think it does. In that example you're using sets, not hash maps, which are completely different:

```
(clojure.set/superset? #{:a 1 :b 2} #{:a :b})

=> true
```

Comment: You can use the namespaced keyword `::not-found` in your `:not-found` example to basically eliminate the chance of a collision (unless someone is deliberately trying).

Answer (score 2):

Your `matches?` function looks good to me, though I'd probably remove the let in this case, as it removes a bit of clutter. I'd also rename it to something more precise, though this is the best I can come up with just now:

```
(defn contains-kv?
  "Returns true if the key k is present in the given map m and it's value matches v."
  [m k v]
  (= (m k) v))
```